# The origin of constant C.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Using the handbook "Handbook of exact solution to the ordinary differential equations" by Polyanin, the formula to solve the first order differential equation of the form,

$g(x) \cdot y' = f_1(x) \cdot y + f_0(x)$

is,

$y = C \cdot e^F + e^F \cdot \int e^{-F} \cdot \frac{f_0(x)}{g(x)} dx $

where,

$ F = \int \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} dx$

The question is where does the constant C comes from?  From which integral? Integral of F or y?  Let suppose for the sake of argument, the integral is from $0$ to $x$ or $y(x) = y$ and $y(1)=a$ and $g(x) = 1$ $f_0 = x$ and $f_1 = x^2$ for integral range of $\int_1^x$. Which integral the constant C belongs to? Or how do I calculate C?

Comment: I may post a more detailed answer, but in the meantime suppose your integrals run 'twixt $x_0$ and $x$; then if you let $x = x_0$ you obtain $y(x_0) = C$, since the integrals all vanish, having the same upper and lower limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that this problem will be greatly clarified by the introduction of explicit limits of integration, as we shall do below; second, the given equation

$g(x)y'(x) = f_1(x) y(x) + f_0(x) \tag 1$

may only be sensibly cast in the form

$y'(x) = \dfrac{f_1(x)}{g(x)}y(x) + \dfrac{f_0(x)}{g(x)} \tag 2$

in the event that

$g(x) \ne 0 \tag 3$

over its entire range of definition.  In light of these observations, we shall assume that (1) is to be taken over some interval

$I = [x_0, x_1] \subset \Bbb R, \tag 4$

and that

$\forall x \in I, \; g(x) \ne 0; \tag 5$

under such assumptions, the form (2) is legitamit, and in fact we might as well avail ourselves of the notational simplification

$p(x) = \dfrac{f_1(x)}{g(x)}, \; q(x) = \dfrac{f_0(x)}{g(x)}; \tag 6$

then (2) becomes

$y'(x) = p(x)y(x) + q(x); \tag 7$

in addition, we place the boundary condition

$y(x_0) = y_0 \tag 8$

on $y(x)$.

At this point we may set

$F(x) = \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x p(s) \; ds, \tag 9$

and multiply (7) through by

$e^{-F(x)} = \exp(-F(x)) \tag{10}$

to obtain

$e^{-F(x)} y'(x) = e^{-F(x)}p(x)y(x) + e^{-F(x)}q(x), \tag{11}$

or

$e^{-F(x)}y'(x) - e^{-F(x)}p(x)y(x) = e^{-F(x)}q(x); \tag{12}$

we observe that (9) implies

$F'(x) = p(x), \tag{13}$

and also that

$F(x_0) = 0, \tag{14}$

so that

$e^{F(x_0)} = 1; \tag{15}$

we compute

$(e^{-F(x)}y(x))' = (e^{-F(x)})'y(x) + e^{-F(x)}y'(x) = -F'(x)e^{-F(x)}y(x) + e^{-F(x)}y'(x)$
$= -p(x) e^{-F(x)}y(x) + e^{-F(x)}y'(x) = e^{-F(x)}q(x), \tag{16}$

where we have used (12) and (13) in arriving at (16), which we may integrate 'twixt $x_0$ and $x$:

$e^{-F(x)}y(x) - y(x_0) = e^{-F(x)}y(x) - e^{-F(x_0)}y(x_0)$
$= \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x (e^{-F(s)}y(s))' \; ds = \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds, \tag{17}$

whence

$e^{-F(x)}y(x) = y(x_0) + \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds, \tag{18}$

and

$y(x) = e^{F(x)} \left ( y(x_0) + \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds \right ) = y_0e^{F(x)} + e^{F(x)}\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds, \tag{19}$

which may be readily checked by direct differentiation:

$y'(x) = (e^{F(x)})'\left ( y(x_0) + \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds \right ) + e^{F(x)}  \left ( y(x_0) + \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds \right )'$
$= F'(x)e^{F(x)}\left ( y(x_0) + \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds \right ) + e^{F(x)} \left ( \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds \right )'$
$= p(x)e^{F(x)}\left ( y(x_0) + \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x e^{-F(s)}q(s) \; ds \right ) + e^{F(x)}e^{-F(x)}q(x) = p(x)y(x) + q(x); \tag{20}$

we thus see that (19) is indeed a complete solution to (7), with $y(x_0) = y_0$.

We are now well-positioned to address at least some of the specific questions posed by our OP Aschoolar in his closing remarks.  "Where does the constant $C$ come from?"  Well, it ultimately originates in $y_0$; in fact, $C = y_0$, as we have shown here.  It arises naturally in (17) from the lower limit of

$\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x (F(s)y(s))' \; ds = e^{-F(x)}y(x) - y_0, \tag{21}$
by virtue of (15); since I'm not sure what is being asked "for the sake of argument", I won't attempt to address these queries.  We "calculate $C$" by setting $C = y_0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$gy'=f_1y+f_0\implies y'=\frac{f_1}gy+\frac{f_0}g$$

Denote $F_1=\frac{f_1}g$ and $F_0=\frac{f_0}g$. Multiplying both sides of the last equation by $e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}$ (this is the integrating factor of the above first order linear ODE with variable coefficients $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$), we get,

$$y'e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}=F_1 ye^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}+F_0e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}$$

Rewriting, we get,

$$y'e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}-y(F_1e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx})=F_0e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}$$

Notice that the LHS is the chain rule applied on $ye^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}$, so we have,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(ye^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}\right)=F_0e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}$$

The constant of integration $C$ you have there is obtained by integrating both sides of this last equation. Integrating both sides, we get,

$$ye^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}=C+\int F_0e^{-\int F_1~\mathrm dx}~\mathrm dx$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^{\int F_1~\mathrm dx}$ (or $e^F$ as you write) gives the final result in your post.